# Как включить в Android Studio подсветку GLSL синтаксиса? (шейдерный язык)

Tags: android-studio, шейдеры, glsl

после переустановки Android studio перестала работать подсветка GLSL синтаксиса, Подскажите пожалуйста как включить?

(OpenGL Shading Language) шейдерный язык

Comment: Что такое GLSL? Думаю стоит рассказать об этом в вопросе.

Comment: (OpenGL Shading Language) шейдерный язык

Comment: По идее никак (все языки учесть невозможно), разве что самому настроить подсветку синтаксиса для данного языка.

Comment: в Web storm можно установить плагин, он находится поиском внутри подменю плагинов в настройках ide, может в андроид студии так же? она же тоже intellij

Comment: но сильно он не поможет, разве что подсветка..

Comment: подсветка работала на версии Android Studio 2.3 а после переустановки на 3.3 перестала :(

Answer (score 0):

спасибо помогло, действительно спустя 2 дня после установки, студия сама предложила установить нужный плагин, и все, glsl засветился как новогодняя елка:) 
Обожаю студию, вот бы ее еще научить под винду компилировать, а то GooglePlay уже мертв.